# creacion de evento en full calendar me arroja una fecha fin (end) con un dia mas de la cuenta y datos de hora innecesarios

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

en esta imagen muestro de que va, estoy usando fullcalendar 
[image: imagen de full calendar]

en esta imagen muestro los dias seleccionados
[image: los dias que selecciono]

en esta muestro el primer error , el calendario antes de guardar la fecha ya me esta trayendo un dato mal , si creo cualquier fecha se le agrega un dia 
mas , si creo un evento para hoy , me muestra que la fecha de fin es mañana.
[image: el dia final se le esta añadiendo un dia mas en la creacion]

esto no lo entiendo del todo por que pasa...
[image: aqui al leer los datos de vuelta me trae estos datos]

el siguiente codigo es como tengo construido el calendar

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var initialLocaleCode = 'es'; 

       var date = new Date();
       var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
       var mm = (date.getMonth()+1).toString().length == 1 ? "0"+(date.getMonth()+1).toString() : (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
       var dd  = (date.getDate()).toString().length == 1 ? "0"+(date.getDate()).toString() : (date.getDate()).toString();


     initThemeChooser({
     init: function(themeSystem) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({




      header: {
         language: 'es',
         left: 'prev,next today',
         center: 'title',
         right: 'month,basicWeek,listWeek,listDay',
              },
      displayEventTime: true,
      locale: initialLocaleCode,
      buttonIcons: true, 
      weekNumbers: true,
      weekNumberTitle: 'Semana',
      defaultView: 'listDay',
      defaultDate: yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd,
      navLinks: true,
      editable: false,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,


      select: function(start, end) {
         var check = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
         var today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

      if (check >= today) {   
          $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
          $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
          $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
      }

      else {
          swal({
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Error',
        text: 'No pueden crear ni editar eventos en fechas anteriores a hoy!',
      });
      }
  },

  eventConstraint: {
                start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                end: '2100-01-01' // hard coded goodness unfortunately
            },


  eventMouseover: function (data, event, view) {

            tooltip = '<div class="tooltiptopicevent" style="width:auto;height:auto;background:#F7F7F7;position:absolute;z-index:10001;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px ;line-height: 200%;box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #1F1F1F;border: 3px solid #FC0000;border-radius: 6px;">'+'<u>'+ '<div align="center" style="">'+ 'VISTA RÁPIDA DEL EVENTO' + '</u>'  + '</div>' +'<u>'+ 'TITULO' +'</u>'+ ': ' + data.title + '</br>' +'<u>'+ 'HORA DEL EVENTO' +'</u>'+ ': ' + data.hora + '</br>' +'<u>'+ 'LUGAR' +'</u>'+ ': ' + data.lugar + '</div>';


            $("body").append(tooltip);
            $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
                $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
                $('.tooltiptopicevent').fadeIn('500');
                $('.tooltiptopicevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
                }).mousemove(function (e) {
                $('.tooltiptopicevent').css('top', e.pageY + -160);
                $('.tooltiptopicevent').css('left', e.pageX + -100);
            });


        },
        eventMouseout: function (data, event, view) {
            $(this).css('z-index', 8);

            $('.tooltiptopicevent').remove();

        },




      eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.bind('dblclick', function() {
          $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
          $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
          $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
          $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
          var form = hanyerck || $('#hanyerck')[0];
          var keys = Object.keys(event);
          while(key = keys.shift()){

            try{
              var input = form.querySelector('input[name="'+key+'"],select[name="'+key+'"],textarea[name="'+key+'"]');

              if(input.nodeName == 'SELECT'){
                var option = input.querySelector('[value="'+event[key]+'"]');
                if(option != null){
                  option.setAttribute('selected','selected');
                }
              }else{
                input.value = event[key];
              }
            }catch(e){}
          }
        });
      },



      events: [
      <?php foreach($events as $event): 

        $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
        $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
        if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
          $start = $start[0];
        }else{
          $start = $event['start'];
        }
        if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
          $end = $end[0];
        }else{
          $end = $event['end'];
        }
      ?>
        {
          id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
          title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
          start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
          end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
          color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
          lugar: '<?php echo $event['lugar']; ?>',
          motivo: '<?php echo $event['motivo']; ?>',
          fuente: '<?php echo $event['fuente']; ?>',
          tipo: '<?php echo $event['tipo']; ?>',
          hora: '<?php echo $event['hora']; ?>',
          fotografo: '<?php echo $event['fotografo']; ?>',
          descripcion: '<?php echo $event['descripcion']; ?>',
          reportero: '<?php echo $event['reportero']; ?>',
          etiquetas: '<?php echo $event['etiquetas']; ?>',
          razonmodificacion: '<?php echo $event['razonmodificacion']; ?>',
          creadopor: '<?php echo $event['creadopor']; ?>'
        },
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      ]
    });//aqui termina el full calendar
},

change: function(themeSystem) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'themeSystem', themeSystem);
                              }
      });// initThemeChooser





    $.each($.fullCalendar.locales, function(localeCode) {
      $('#locale-selector').append(
        $('<option/>')
          .attr('value', localeCode)
          .prop('selected', localeCode == initialLocaleCode)
          .text(localeCode)
      );
    });

    // when the selected option changes, dynamically change the calendar option
    $('#locale-selector').on('change', function() {
      if (this.value) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'locale', this.value);
      }
    });
  });//document ready

 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 

</script>
```

Comment: Tu idea es que al clickear un día en fullcalendar, dicho día se refleje en tu input?

Comment: el dia ya esta reflejado, lo que no hace correctamente es mostrar el dia final.
cuando presiono un dia en mi calendario muestro el la fecha inicial(la de hoy) bien , pero la fecha final, no deberia ser mañana.

Comment: y si a la línea donde *seteas* el día (*dd*), le agregas esto `(date.replace(/-/g, '\/').getDate()).toString().length == 1` , como te lo muestra?

Comment: Resta un segundo a la fecha final con js y listo, el tema acá es que al momento de seleccionar la fecha final selecciona las 24 hrs del dia y no 23:59:59

Comment: me podrias explicar como hacerlo? aun tengo la duda ...